# Trouble Removing extra page Break

Tags: excel, page-break, vba

I have some code that creates a report onto a temporary worksheet in a printable format. In that code, it calls upon `Sub SetPageBreaks` (below code). I am having trouble with removing a specific page break that is set between columns `G:H`.

```
Sub SetPageBreaks(SheetObj As Worksheet)

    Dim TotRow%, LinesPerPg%, NumPgs%, Page%

    TotRow = SheetObj.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LinesPerPg = 56
    NumPgs = RoundUp(TotRow / LinesPerPg)

    With SheetObj
        .ResetAllPageBreaks
        For Page = 1 To NumPgs
            .Rows(LinesPerPg * Page + 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        Next Page
        .Columns("J").PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        .Columns("H").PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
    End With

End Sub

Function RoundUp(ByVal Number As Double) As Long
    RoundUp = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Number, 0)
End Function
```

Between columns `I:J` is the final column of the page (it needs to fit the entire width of the page, some scaling is to be expected). Why is my code not removing the break on col `H`?

### Edit (New Coding Attempt):

I have updated my code to the following, with no success (after adjusting the margins to my preferences, then adding the `.FitToPagesWide`, it is cutting of my last column.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetPageBreaks(SheetObj As Worksheet)

    Dim TotRow%, LinesPerPg%, NumPgs%, Page%

    TotRow = SheetObj.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LinesPerPg = 56
    NumPgs = RoundUp(TotRow / LinesPerPg)

    With SheetObj
        .ResetAllPageBreaks
        For Page = 1 To NumPgs
            .Rows(LinesPerPg * Page + 1).PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        Next Page
        With .PageSetup
            .HeaderMargin = 21.6
            .FooterMargin = 21.6
            .TopMargin = 86.4
            .LeftMargin = 18
            .RightMargin = 18
            .BottomMargin = 54
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = False
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some scaling to occur, you have to let Excel know how to do it. At the beginning of the With block, add:

```
.PageSetup.Zoom = False
.PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A:$I"
.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = False
```

Your last 2 With block lines shouldn't be necessary anymore.

Comment: Also set the PrintArea before .FitToPagesWide:
.PrintArea = "$A:$I"

Comment: I added `.PageSetup.PrintArea = SheetObj.UsedRange.Address` with the same results (it was done prior to any other `PageSetup`)

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to add `.PageSetup.Zoom = False`, as once this is set the [`.FitToPagesWide` controls how the worksheet is scaled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/pagesetup-zoom-property-excel). Thanks for sending me to the right direction though, so your answer did solve my problem.

Comment: Edited the answer accordingly.